# Mockito ArgumentCaptor is capturing lots of repeated records

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito and JUnit to test a multithreaded application. Here's some of the code in question:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<MessageCreator> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MessageCreator.class);

jmsHandler.put(message);

Mockito.verify(mockJmsTemplate, Mockito.after(10000).times(4)).send(messageCaptor.capture());
```

The `jmsHandler.put(message)` line puts a `String` into the application, which goes onto a `BlockingQueue` and starts with the multithreading parts. I then wait on the method to execute 4 times over the next 10 seconds and capture the results.

The application should spit out 4 instances of `MessageCreator`, which, for my purposes, is just an object containing a `String` that I'll then compare to the expected output. The logging during the test confirms that the 4 messages are being created.

When I tried to loop through the `ArgumentCaptor`'s `getAllValues()` method to check the results, though, I noticed that the `List` is duplicating my program's output literally millions of times. It should have 4 objects in it, but the last run had 6,984,988.

This number seems to be variable to some small extent, but it changes drastically when I play around with the test timings in debug mode. For example, if I set a breakpoint at the `jmsHandler` line, step over that, and wait for the application to finish processing before even starting the `Mockito.verify(...)` step, the `List` size plummets to a "mere" 158,636 objects.

Has anyone else run into this kind of issue before? Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

EDIT: Here's a self-contained example of the test and program structure:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

public class MultiThreadTest {
    private Input inputHandler;
    @Mock
    private JmsTemplate mockJmsTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

        inputHandler = new Input();
        inputHandler.setQueue(queue);

        Output outputHandler = new Output();
        outputHandler.setQueue(queue);
        outputHandler.setJmsTemplate(mockJmsTemplate);
        new Thread(outputHandler).start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessage() {
        ArgumentCaptor<OutputMessageCreator> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(OutputMessageCreator.class);

        String inMessage = "testMessage";

        List<String> expectedMessages = new ArrayList<String>(4);

        inputHandler.put(inMessage);

        Mockito.verify(mockJmsTemplate, Mockito.after(10000).times(4)).send(messageCaptor.capture());
        System.out.println("Number: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().size());
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(1)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(2)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(3)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(4)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(5)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(6)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(7)));
        System.out.println("Equal: " + messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(messageCaptor.getAllValues().get(8)));

        List<String> outMsgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (OutputMessageCreator creator : messageCaptor.getAllValues()) {
            outMsgs.add(creator.getMsg());
        }
        assertEquals(expectedMessages, outMsgs);
    }

    private class Input {
        private BlockingQueue<String> queue;

        public void put(String msg) {
            try {
                queue.put(msg);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setQueue(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }
    }

    private class Output implements Runnable {
        private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
        private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
        private int counter = 1;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                String msg = null;
                try {
                    msg = queue.take();
                    String[] messagesOut = new String[4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        messagesOut[i] = msg + "-" + counter++;
                    }

                    for (String messageOut : messagesOut) {
                        System.out.println(messageOut);
                        jmsTemplate.send(new OutputMessageCreator(messageOut));
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void setQueue(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
            this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
        }
    }

    private class OutputMessageCreator implements MessageCreator {
        private String msg;

        public OutputMessageCreator(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText(msg);
            return message;
        }

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output from running that test:

```
testMessage-1
testMessage-2
testMessage-3
testMessage-4
Number: 5392168
Equal: true
Equal: false
Equal: false
Equal: false
Equal: true
Equal: false
Equal: false
Equal: false
Equal: true
```

Comment: Does the problem happen without an ArgumentCaptor? If yes, you may want to change your title. Either way, you may want to provide a working example.

Comment: @jdebon Thank you for the feedback. The problem is with the `ArgumentCaptor`. The test itself is creating only the 4 messages, as expected, but the `ArgumentCaptor` is capturing them repeatedly millions of times. In other words, `getAllValues()` returns [msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg1, ...]. I've attached a recreation of the issue to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in Mockito at some point:

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/345

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/379

The issues seem to imply this was fixed in Mockito 2 or 2.1, but I am using 2.0.41-beta and tried 2.4.0 and 2.8.9 and got the same results. In some of the comments of the github issues, it appears that there's a work around of sorts.

This line of the code:

```java
Mockito.verify(mockJmsTemplate, Mockito.after(10000).times(4)).send(messageCaptor.capture());
```

can be replaced with this:

```java
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Mockito.verify(mockJmsTemplate, Mockito.times(4)).send(messageCaptor.capture());
```

I've commented on issue 379 to see if the fix was actually released, but it seems like this work around will do the trick for now.

Comment: Still an issue in latest Mockito (currently 3.12.4). I also commented on the existing github issue that this bug is still present/